# Google App Engine Billing

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there anyway to receive emails with a monthly billing statement of costs on Google App Engine? I have to submit invoices to the cost center at my employer and it makes it difficult to provide with only the online account and I don't want to give the cost center access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.  Google currently provides only [Transaction History](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#invoices).  They should improve that.  I think many people would appreciate what you're asking about.  I've just starred this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6994) for European VAT invoices, please do so too and add a comment if it's a non Euro invoice you require.

In your situation I would create a custom spreadsheet invoice layout and import the transaction log into it once a month.

Comment: That is what I seemed to have worked out. It is not a huge deal, but it is a pain having to do it every month.